# Daemon thread with infinite loop not terminating

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple test program (garage simulation) with several threads (`Vehicle`, `MysteryVehicle`, `Observer` objects) instantiated and started. Only the `Observer` object is a daemon thread running an infinite loop.

After all non-daemon threads terminate, `Observer` thread never does and the loop is executed infinitely (so this isn't some buffered output after the daemon thread *really* terminates - it does go on forever).

All of the non-daemon threads print something to the console just before exiting their `run()` methods, and it clearly shows all of them really terminated. I also didn't call `join()` on the daemon thread. When printing out all currently running threads, `observer` is listed as well, so my guess is that this daemon thread isn't terminating properly.

The complete code can be found on [this commit](https://github.com/ngrahovac/Garage/commit/f2247723773feaf982e5398805afecf824b57faa).

Below you can see all threads created, started and where exactly is `join()` called.

**Main.java**

```
package garage;

import java.util.Set;

import garage.model.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Platform platform = new Platform();
        Vehicle.platform = platform;
        platform.print();

        Vehicle[] vehicles = new Vehicle[30];
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            vehicles[i] = new Vehicle();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            vehicles[i].start();
        }

        Observer observer = new Observer();
        observer.platform = platform;
        observer.start();

        MysteryVehicle mysteryVehicle = new MysteryVehicle();
        mysteryVehicle.start();

        try {
            mysteryVehicle.join();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                vehicles[i].join();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("before");
        platform.print();
        System.out.println("after");

        synchronized (Platform.lock) {
            System.out.println("END");
            System.out.println(platform.flag); // checks whether wait() was called anytime
        }

        Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();

        for (Thread t : threads) {
            System.out.println(t.getName());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Observer.java**

```
package garage.model;

public class Observer extends Thread {
    public Platform platform;
    static int count = 0;

    {
        setName("observer");
        setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
        setDaemon(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (Platform.lock) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(++count);
                    platform.print();
                    Platform.lock.wait(5000); // hack for when there is no meaningful loop condition
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Platform.lock.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Vehicle run() method** - relevant part

```
public void run() {
        ... 
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

**MysteryVehicle run() method** - relevant part

```
public void run() {
        synchronized (Platform.lock) {
            System.out.println("And the vehicle disappears!");
            ...
        }

    }
```

All of the relevant thread messages are printed out to the console.
*done* - 30 times, *And the vehicle disappears!*, *before*, *after*, *END*, *true*

This is the list of all of the running threads:

```
Attach Listener
main
Common-Cleaner
JavaFX Application Thread
Signal Dispatcher
Finalizer
InvokeLaterDispatcher
Reference Handler
QuantumRenderer-0
observer
Thread-2
JavaFX-Launcher
```

Since the program doesn't terminate and the `print()` function the `run()` method of `observer` calls is executed infinitely, what is it that prevents the daemon thread from terminating?

What am I missing here?

Comment: "what is it that prevents the daemon thread from terminating?"
I think it is the code of its run method, which has an infinite loop and no return statement.

Comment: `Platform.exit()` is not invoked nor are there any UI objects to be closed, so does `main()` actually return?  Try adding a `println()` after `launch()`.

Comment: Re, "after all non-daemon threads terminate..." Don't forget that `main()` is called by a non-daemon thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect `main()` never returns, so the *main* thread (and perhaps some of those FX threads) are still running.

From the [Application doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-):

> The launch method does not return until the application has exited,
>   either via a call to Platform.exit or all of the application windows
>   have been closed.

The posted code has no window to close nor is `Platform.exit()` invoked.

Comment: Yes, this was it. I never had the need for an infinite loop inside a daemon thread keeping it alive while the main thread was running. They usually terminated after a certain condition was met so I had no idea.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, calling join on daemon thread is a bad idea.The idea behind using daemon thread is it will not halt JVM from exiting. What you can do is send an interrupt to that thread and call join after that.

Comment: As I said, I **did not** call `join()` on daemon thread and the program still halts.

Comment: @0lt 2nd to last paragraph in your original question says, "Since the program _doesn't_ terminate...", but your comment above says, "...and the program _still halts._"  Which is it? Does the process terminate? or does the process not terminate?

Comment: @SolomonSlow my bad, it doesn't halt. The program never exits.